# Monitor /var/log/messages file for specific keyword

Tags: linux, operating-system, monitoring, redhat, message

we need to monitor /var/log/messages for a specific keyword "Critical"

We need to monitor the same every minute and the moment it appears in messages file it should send an email.

It should only send the latest entry in messages files.

There is no specific time when it can generate the keyword

Can you please provide any idea for the same

Thank You in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for software  tools and recommendations, tutorials, research, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: AND, please learn to use the search feature, `[linux] monitor log file` returns 300+ Q/As. The first 3 look like they would answer your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below command to monitor /var/log/messages/ with specific keyword.

**#  tail -f /var/log/messages | grep "critical"**